# difference between release tag/property and compilerVersion tag/property used in maven-compiler-plugin. issues when upgrading to java 11

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

What is the difference between `release` tag/property and `compilerVersion` tag/property used in `maven-compiler-plugin` as we are facing issue when using release tag when upgrading to java 11 when we build using `<compilerVersion>11<compilerVersion>` in pom.xml it works but fails with below error when we use `<release>11</release>`

error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project Test: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
10:54:54 [ERROR] 
10:54:54 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
10:54:54 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
10:54:54 [ERROR] 
10:54:54 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
10:54:54 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Are you sure JDK 11 comes in your PATH before any version prior to 9?

Answer (score 0):

[`<compilerVersion>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerVersion):

> Version of the compiler to use [...], if `fork` is set to `true`.

[`<release>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release):

> The -release argument for the Java compiler, supported since Java9